# Añadir un archivo .js en un archivo.blade.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una plantilla con un formulario con diversos campos, algunos de ellos son solo para aquellos usuarios que sean menores de edad y están todos dentro de un div con el id=formulariomayores

```
@csrf

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="dni">DNI<br></label>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="dni" value="{{ old('dni', $cliente->dni)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="nombre"></label>
        <br>Nombre del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="nombre" value="{{ old('nombre', $cliente->nombre)}}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="apellidos"></label>
        <br>Apellidos del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="apellidos" value="{{ old('apellidos', $cliente->apellidos) }}">

</div>



<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Url para el cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="url" value="{{ old('url', $cliente->url) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Codigo Postal del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="codigopostal" value="{{ old('codigopostal', $cliente->codigopostal) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Dirreción del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="direccion" value="{{ old('direccion', $cliente->direccion) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Localidad del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="localidad" value="{{ old('localidad', $cliente->localidad) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Provincia del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="provincia" value="{{ old('provincia', $cliente->provincia) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Pais del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="pais" value="{{ old('pais', $cliente->pais) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Email<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $cliente->email) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Telefono del cliente<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="telefono" value="{{ old('telefono', $cliente->telefono) }}">

</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label for="fechana"></label>
        <br>Fecha de Nacimiento<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="date" id="fechana" name="fechana" value="{{ old('fechana', $cliente->fechana)}}">

</div>

<br>
<br>

<br>
<div id="formulariomayores" style="display: none;" class="form-group">

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
<div class="form-group">

    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Nombre completo del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="nombrecompletome" value="{{ old('nombrecompletome', $cliente->nombrecompletome) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Direccion del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="direccionme" value="{{ old('direccionme', $cliente->direccionme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Localidad del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="localidadme" value="{{ old('localidadme', $cliente->localidadme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Provincia del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="provinciame" value="{{ old('provinciame', $cliente->provinciame) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>País del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="paisme" value="{{ old('paisme', $cliente->paisme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Email del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="emailme" value="{{ old('emailme', $cliente->emailme) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Telefono del tutol del menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="telefonome" value="{{ old('telefonome', $cliente->telefonome) }}">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <br>
    <label></label>
        <br>Vinculación del tutol con el menor<br>
        <input class="form-control bg-light shadow-sm" type="text" name="vinculacionconmenor" value="{{ old('vinculacionconmenor', $cliente->vinculacionconmenor) }}">

</div>
</div>
</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">{{$btnText}}</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link btn-block btn-danger btn-lg" href="{{ route('cliente.index')}}">Cancelar</a>
```

Por otra parte tengo una función JavaScript que me debería calcular la edad, sacando la diferencia entre la fecha actual y la fecha que se añade al formulario.

```
fecha = document.getElementById("fechana");

fecha.addEventListener("change", calculateAge);

function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var birthday_arr = birthday.split("/");
    var birthday_date = new Date(birthday_arr[2], birthday_arr[1] - 1, birthday_arr[0]);
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - birthday_date.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs);
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 2022);
}

var age = calculateAge("$cliente->fechana");
alert( age );
let fechana= $("#fechana").val();
```

Y por último tengo un archivo .blade.php en el cual debería añadir mi función .js pero no sé como hacerlo, dicho archivo es:

```
@extends('plantilla')
@section('titulo', 'Creación de Clientes')
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mayoria_edad").click(function(){
      alert("Rellene los datos del tutor por favor");
   });
});</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#mayoria_edad").click(function(evento){
      if ($("#mayoria_edad").attr("checked")){
         $("#formulariomayores").css("display", "block");
      }else{
         $("#formulariomayores").css("display", "none");
      }
   });
});
</script>
@section('contenedor')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-lg-6 mx-auto"></div>

        <br>


@include('partials/validation-errors')

<form class="bg-white shadow rounded py-3 px-4" method="POST" action="{{route('cliente.store')}}">
<h1 class="display-4">Creación de Clientes</h1>
<hr>
    @include('carclientes/_form', ['btnText'=>'Guardar'])

</form>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Mi mayor duda es como compilar todo para que me funcione a la hora de rellenar el formulario. Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: no tiene sentido ... si vez estas colocando el archivo de jsquery ... deberia bastar con agregar el tuyo propio de igual manera...

Comment: Pero para añadirlo debería utilizar algún empaquetador de módulo como webpack?

Comment: Y que no tiene sentido? Es que acabo de empezar a programar en estos lenguajes y le hecho muchas horas pero no consigo hacerlo bien. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: si puede ir por eso o implementarlo en tu plantilla principal

Comment: tal vez en el sitio de foro de laravel o si tienen chat como slack consigas mas ayuda rapida ...

Comment: Okey, muchísimas gracias, entonces si implemento el codigo del fichero.js en mi plantilla debería ir directamente?

Comment: pues si no debe haber ningun problema